# Is it possible to define strings that aren't allowed for MVC Data Annotations?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

Basically, I'm wondering exactly what the title says:  Is it possible to define certain strings as not allowed through MVC's Data Annotations?

As an example, say I have a string field: `Name` and I really don't like the name Ned.  So is there a way to set up a Data Annotation that displays an `ErrorMessage` if a user enters Ned into `Name`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure you can create a custom attribute to do that.  It can quite simply checks against a blacklist of names and return true or false depending on the outcome. Creating a class that inherits from the `ValidationAttribute` is probably the way to go.

**Example**

```
public class NameAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        // do your blacklist logic here.            
        return true;
    }
}
```

Try this Microsoft training course on [Custom Validation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2010trainingcourse_aspnetmvccustomvalidation.aspx)

Comment: Ahh, could you perhaps elaborate a bit with code or point me in the right direction for research?

Comment: Many thanks!  I hadn't thought to do something like that.  I kept looking around for something kind of already built in but I guess I should have thought to built it up myself.

Comment: how/where do I implement this in the ViewModel so that it is recognised as an error in the ModelState on form submission?